# Using AA Aviator Awards

Tags: usa, loyalty-programs, american-airlines

I signed up for a US Airways, now AA Aviator Credit card and earned 50,000 miles.  When I go online to redeem there are two choices of seats, Economy Miles Saver (none available for my dates) and Economy AA Anytime (some available).  Am I eligible for both of these?

Comment: The difference between the categories is usually just how many miles you need to use.  So you should be able use either fare if you have enough miles.

Comment: *Saver* and *Anytime* refer to seats, not to your frequent flyer status. The answer to this question (and for Delta) will be substantially similar to that of *[What is the difference between Saver and Standard awards on United Mileage Plus?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7915)*

Answer (score 1):

These are just different tiers of rewards. Like most frequent flyer programs, AA has a tiered system where the Saver awards (the ones that you rightly note are not available) are cheaper, but go faster. Look at [AA's reward chart](https://www.aa.com/i18n/AAdvantage/redeemMiles/american-airlines-award-chart.jsp) for the most up to date info.

Answer (score 0):

American Airlines draws no distinction between miles earned from credit card bonuses, credit card spending, or any other partners (for the purposes of *elite status asssignment* it is a different story). An AAdvantage redeemable mile is an AAdvantage redeemable mile. Put another way, the miles you earn from the card go into the same co-mingled pot as the miles from your other activity, whether from flying, bonuses, partners, customer service credit, transfers, or gifts.

The [AAdvantage Terms & Conditions](https://www.aa.com/i18n/AAdvantage/termsConditions.jsp) do not indicate any restrictions on who may redeem for the [general award ticket types](https://www.aa.com/i18n/AAdvantage/redeemMiles/award-travel.jsp). MileSAAver awards are somewhat analogous to discount tickets; they are tightly capacity-controlled and heavily restricted. AAnytime awards are somewhat analogous to full-fare tickets; they are much more costly (generally double the redemption level by the [award chart / redemption table](https://www.aa.com/i18n/AAdvantage/redeemMiles/american-airlines-award-chart.jsp)), but are flexible, can be used on any available seat, and come with a few perqs like access to ["Preferred" seats](https://www.aa.com/i18n/urls/seats.jsp?anchorLocation=DirectURL&title=seats) in the economy cabin.

In fact, holders of AAdvantage credit cards, including the Barclays Aviator cards with annual fees, may qualify for *additional* discounts for MileSAAver seats to certain destinations under the [Reduced Mileage Awards](https://www.aa.com/i18n/AAdvantage/redeemMiles/reduced-mileage-awards.jsp) program.